# Problema con una etiqueta <a> en Flask

Tags: html, python, flask

estoy creando una app en flask y de momento estoy en el login. En el login estoy intentando que si el usuario no tiene cuenta le de click a una etiqueta  y esta lo redireccione a la pagina de registro (index.html) y que si el usuario esta en la pestaña de registro y tiene cuenta lo mande a la pestaña de pagina de login (isesion.html)
en las paginas html (sin nada de flask) los vinculos funcionan correctamente, pero es cuando los pongo en flask que da error 400. a continuación les comparto mi codigo

aplicacion en flask (dudo que sea aqui el problema)

```
app = Flask(__name__)

app.config["TEMPLATES_AUTO_RELOAD"] = True

app.config["SESSION_PERMANENT"] = False
app.config["SESSION_TYPE"] = "filesystem"
Session(app)


'''
SELECT usuarios.nombres FROM usuarios INNER JOIN prestamo on usuarios.carnet = prestamo.carnet
INNER JOIN libros on prestamo.id_libro = libros.id_libro INNER JOIN isbn_libro on libros.id_libro = isbn_libro.id_libro WHERE isbn_libro.isbn = "9786071505408";


'''
db = SQL("sqlite:///database/biblo.db")

#Registroppp
@app.route("/")
@app.route("/index")
@app.route('/register', methods=["GET","POST"])

def registro():
    session.clear() #Sinceramente no recuerdo

    if request.method == "POST":
        carreras = ["Arquitectura", "Ing. Computación", "Ing. Eléctrica", "Ing. Eléctrónica", "Ing. Química" ]
        a = db.execute('SELECT * FROM Libros')
        print(a)
        nombres = request.form.get("nombres")
        apellidos = request.form.get("apellidos")
        carrera = request.form.get("carrera")
        numero = request.form.get("telefono") # Verificar lo del numero de telefono con el regex
        strcarnet = request.form.get("carnet")
        correo = request.form.get("email")
        hash = generate_password_hash(request.form.get("pass"))

        if carrera not in carreras:
            return apology("Esa no es una carrera", 400)
        try:
            carnet = int(strcarnet)
            celular = int(numero)
        except ValueError:
            return apology("Ingrese solo numeros")

        #Ingresando datos a la database
        db.execute("INSERT INTO usuarios(carnet, nombres, apellidos, email, hash, carrera, telefono) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)", carnet, nombres, apellidos, correo, hash, carrera, celular)

        return redirect(url_for('inicio'))


    print("a")
    return render_template("index.html")


@app.route('/isesion', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def inicio():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        carnet = request.form.get("carnet")
        print(carnet)

    return render_template('isesion.html')
```

y las paginas:
index.html

```
{%extends "layout.html" %}

{% block title %}
    - Index
{% endblock %}

{% block links%}
    <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#" > Simon </a> </li>
    <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#" > Funciona </a> </li>
{% endblock %}

{% block contenido%}
<div class="wrapper fadeInDown">
    <div id="formContent">
      <!-- Tabs Titles -->

      <!-- Login Form -->
      <form action="/register" method="POST">
        <input type="text" id="nombres" class="fadeIn second" name="nombres" placeholder="Nombres" required>
        <input type="text" id="apellidos" class="fadeIn second" name="apellidos" placeholder="Apellidos" required>
        <input type="text" id="email" class="fadeIn second" name="email" placeholder="Correo Electrónico" required>
        <input type="password" id="pass" class="fadeIn third" name="pass" placeholder="Contraseña" required>
        <input type="tel" id="telefono" class="fadeIn second" name="telefono" placeholder="Telefono" required>
        <input type="tel" id="carnet" class="fadeIn second" name="carnet" placeholder="Numero de carnet" required>

        <div class="fadeIn third">
        <select class="form-select" aria-label="Default select" id="carrera" name="carrera" required>
          <option selected="">Seleccione una carrera</option>
          <option value="Arquitectura">Arquitectura</option>
          <option value="Ing. Computación">Ing. Computación</option>
          <option value="Ing. Eléctrica">Ing. Eléctrica</option>
          <option value="Ing. Eléctrónica">Ing. Eléctrónica</option>
          <option value="Ing. Química">Ing. Química</option>
        </select>
      </div>
        <!--<input type="password" id="password" class="fadeIn third" name="login" placeholder="Contraseña"> -->
        <input type="submit" id="condicion" class="fadeIn fourth" value="Crear Cuenta">
        <a href="isesion.html" id="condicion" class="myButton fadeIn fourth">Iniciar Sesion</a>

      </form>

      <!-- Remind Passowrd -->

    </div>
  </div>
{% endblock %}
```

isession.html

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block title %}
    Iniciar Sesion
{% endblock %}

{% block contenido %}

    <div class="wrapper fadeInDown">
        <div id="formContent">
          <!-- Tabs Titles -->

          <!-- Login Form -->
          <form action="/isesion">
            <input type="text" id="login" class="fadeIn second" name="carnet" placeholder="Numero de carné">
            <input type="password" id="password" class="fadeIn third" name="login" placeholder="Contraseña">
            <input type="submit" id="condicion" class="fadeIn fourth" value="Iniciar Sesion">
            <a href="index.html" id="condicion" class="myButton fadeIn fourth">Crear cuenta</a>

          </form>

          <!-- Remind Passowrd -->
          <div id="formFooter">
            <a class="underlineHover" href="index.html">Forgot Password?</a>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>

{% endblock %}
```

hasta el momento he probado solo con los archivos html (los archivos sin nada de jinja) y  las etiquetas  funcionan a como deberian.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

para redireccionar a otros links en la app se tiene que usar un href el cual su valor es el nombre de la ruta a como se tiene en la aplicacion. En este caso el link quedaria de la siguiente manera:

```
<a href="/register" id="condicion" class="myButton fadeIn fourth">Crear cuenta</a>
```

ya que en la app la ruta para registrarse tiene ese nombre